# Simplifying expressions fully using Sympy with symbols

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to using Sympy and I want to simplify an expression using symbols. So far here is my code.

```
a,b,x,y,z = symbols('a b x y z')
d = ((a**3 * b)**2 * b ** 4)**(1/3)
print(simplify(d))
```

Which returns

```
(a**6*b**6)**0.333333333333333
```

I would like it to return a^2 b^2 as in the following image

It would also be nice for sympy to return the steps it used, but this seems to be exceedingly difficult to figure out so this is not required but would definitely be helpful.

[image: expression]

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the symbols to be nonnegative, the simplification will happen automatically:

```py
>>> a, b = symbols('a b', nonnegative=True)
>>> ((a**3 * b)**2 * b ** 4)**(S(1)/3)
a**2*b**2
```

Sometimes `powsimp` or `expand` with the `force=True` option will work for expressions involving powers. But in this case, the assumptions need to be made.

Comment: @Seanlatex NB how the one-third is formatted.  Python3 actually performs the `1/3`, the binary expansion of which is infinitely long and is therefore not exactly represented after Python performs the division operation.

Comment: You can also use `root((a**3 * b)**2 * b ** 4, 3)` to enter the expression.